# i18n translations in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rspec

I want to isolate my test from internalization. I use rails 3.2.8 and rspec 2.11.1

I put this code to `spec/support/translations.rb`

```
module I18nHelpers
  def with_translations(locale, translations)
    I18n.backend.store_translations locale, translations
    yield
  ensure
    I18n.reload!
  end
```

end

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include I18nHelpers
end
```

Then I test application helper:

```
describe ApplicationHelper do
  context "messages" do
    it "show body" do
       with_translations :en, navigation: {messages: 'foo'} do
           concat messages_navigation
           assert_test 'span', 'foo'
       end
    end
  end
end
```

But this test falls with message

```
Failure/Error: assert_select 'span', text: /foo/
     MiniTest::Assertion:
        </foo/> expected but was
        <"Messages">.
```

'Messages' is from my real `config/locales/en.yml`
I test #store_translations from console and it works. but when i put line `p I18n.t(translations.key.first)` before `ensure` word in helper module, it shows me old translations.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is a really strange thing you've stumbled on here. I've been playing around in the console but not really sure what's going on. `ensure` is being called before whatever is put after the `yield` call, which shouldn't happen...

Comment: Are you still struggling with this? I've been poking around a bit but haven't quite got a clear answer yet.

Comment: @shioyama, now i test my module on `Messages` word and don't now how to fix it too.

Comment: I see. I'm interested in this issue because I'd like to isolate my test from internationalization this way. This should work... very strange. I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 5):

To have a complete isolation from `I18n` you may want to switch backends like this:

```
def with_translations(locale, translations)
  original_backend = I18n.backend

  I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new Hash.new, true
  I18n.backend.store_translations locale, translations

  yield
ensure
  I18n.backend = original_backend
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I've dug into this problem and I think I have a rough answer. The problem seems to be caused by the fact that rails does not load translations in the locale files until the first call to `I18n.t` is made.

This is a bit old, but still relevant:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/rails-i18n/QFe0GDVRIa0/G7K09NAgqJMJ

> We've considered a lot of different approaches to this and in the end our solution to this is to defer the actual translation loading to the latest possible point. So clients (like Rails) would only register translation sources to I18n and the backend would actually lazy-load them when the first translation needs to be looked up.

So basically, the existing translations are only loaded when you make a call to `I18n.t`. I discovered this while playing around in the console, when I noticed very strange behaviour:

```
irb(main):001:0> def with_translations(locale, translations)
irb(main):002:1>   I18n.backend.store_translations locale, translations
irb(main):003:1>   yield
irb(main):004:1> ensure
irb(main):005:1*   I18n.reload!
irb(main):006:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> I18n.reload!
=> false
irb(main):008:0> with_translations(:en, { :messages => "foo" }) { puts I18n.t :messages }
Messages
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> I18n.t :some_other_string
=> "Some translation"
irb(main):010:0> with_translations(:en, { :messages => "foo" }) { puts I18n.t :messages }
foo
=> nil
```

What is happening has nothing to do with the `ensure` block. We can remove it and the same thing will happen:

```
irb(main):011:0> I18n.reload!
=> false
irb(main):012:0> def with_translations(locale, translations)
irb(main):013:1>   I18n.backend.store_translations locale, translations
irb(main):014:1>   yield
irb(main):015:1> end    
=> nil
irb(main):016:0> with_translations(:en, { :messages => "foo" }) { puts I18n.t :messages }
Messages
```

Even without the reload, it still spits out the original string because the translation in the `I18n.backend.store_translations` call is being overwritten with the original string when `I18n.t` is called. If however you call `I18n.t` *before* the above code, it will work (and leave the translation since there is no `ensure` block reloading the translations).

So basically, the answer is to just call `I18n.t` on an actual translation string to trigger rails to load the existing translations *before* overriding the one you want to change:

```
def with_translations(locale, translations)
  I18n.t translations.keys.first         # to make sure translations are loaded
  I18n.backend.store_translations locale, translations
  yield
ensure
  I18n.reload!
end
```

I have only tried this in the console, but I believe it should work for your rspec test as well. If anyone has deeper insights into this issue I'd be eager to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

After being stuck with a similar issue, I ended up writing a helper like this:

### Helper

```
module TranslationSupport
  def with_translation(replacement_translation)
    I18n.t(".").deep_merge!(replacement_translation)
    begin
      yield
    ensure
      I18n.reload!
    end
  end
end
```

The shortcut here is initialising the backend first with `I18n.t(".")` and then merge in the desired values.

As other answers suggest, alternatively one could initialise the i18n backend then use `I18n.backend.store_translations` to update the values. The downside of this approach is one needs to pass the locale as an argument.

### Usage

This helper can then used it like so:

```
require "rails_helper"
require "support/translation"

RSpec.describe "testing a view with overridden translations" do
  include TranslationSupport

  it "works" do
    translations = {
      homepage: {
        index: {
          label: "Overridden"
        }
      }
    }

    with_translation(translations) do
      # Your action
    end

    # Expectations
  end
end
```

And if you don't want to include the helper each time:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include TranslationSupport
end
```